# Array is not updating properly due to delay in service calls in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I am calling same service multiple times in angular using while loop but due to delay in response of API my array is not updating properly. I want to call certain set of statement once the while loop & all the services response are completed.

```
 GetData(){
    var xyz = [];
    var pqr = [];
    this.startRow = 0;
    this.names=[];
    while(this.startRow <= this.num)
    {
      this.getEmpData();
      this.startRow = this.startRow + this.countRow;
      console.log("Pass1");
      console.log(this.names);
    }
    //due to delay in API response name array is coming as empty
    this.names.forEach(value => {
      xyz.push(value);
    });
   
  }
  getEmpData()
  {    
     this.empService.getEmpData(this.startRow,this.countRow,this.id,this.search).subscribe(data => {
        this.resp = data;
        this.names = this.names.concat(this.resp); 
        console.log(this.names);   
      })
   
  }
```

Response

```
Pass1
[]
Pass1
[]
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(40) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I want the names to be updated in the while loop only or the statement after the while loop to be executed after once the name array is updated. Please help me out with the given issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that like the following:

- Use the `expand` operator, to repeat calling the `getEmpData` method while the condition is valid.
- Use the `reduce` operator that *"Applies an accumulator function over the source Observable, and returns the accumulated result when the source completes, given an optional seed value."*
- Return the observable from `getEmpData` method, instead of subscribing to it.

```js
getData() {
  var xyz = [];
  var pqr = [];
  this.startRow = 0;
  this.names = [];

  this.getEmpData()
    .pipe(
      expand(() => {
        this.startRow = this.startRow + this.countRow;
        return this.startRow <= this.num ? this.getEmpData() : EMPTY;
      }),
      reduce(acc => acc)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      xyz.push(...this.names);
    });
}

getEmpData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.empService
    .getEmpData(this.startRow, this.countRow, this.id, this.search)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.resp = data;
        this.names = this.names.concat(this.resp);
        console.log(this.names);
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great effort @Amer, I had tried your approach getEmpData() method is called as required but after completing all the calls it is not going to the subscribe method. Any suggestion regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: Could you please [stackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/) it?

Comment: Please make sure that you're doing it exactly like the above suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am doing exactly same as you suggested in the answer. There is some issue in reduce & subscribe method. After performing reduce operation the call is not coming to the subscribe method. Sorry to say but stackblitz is not possible for the given code as there are lot of other dependency are also there for the given portion but thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: I created this working [stackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jpkjjv) to simulate what you're trying to do. Check it, please.

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve something similar but in my case response is coming from back end API that I am calling through angular services & I need to append the response every time in the array till the condition is true. Hope you got my point.

Comment: It should work. Could you please include the output of consloe.log here, to know where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I had edited your code to show the problem. In console, it is printing the appended array but it is not printing the console statement that are present in the subscribe method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237097/discussion-between-amer-yousuf-and-sanket-gupta).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry from my side. I had done something wrong while api call which is creating that issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use async-await in your getEmpData() method:

```
 async getEmpData()
  {    
      const data = await this.empService.getEmpData(this.startRow,this.countRow,this.id,this.search).toPromise();
      this.resp = data;
      this.names = this.names.concat(this.resp); 
      console.log(this.names);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but the given approach doesn't work for me. I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: You'd actually need to do the await on `this.getEmpData();` too since that also needs to wait. I'd suggest to do everything that you do after `this.getEmpData();` in the subscribe though. That way you don't need to use async/await explicitely. E.g. you'd push `data` into `xzy` (so in chunks instead of at once).

Comment: Thank you @GunnarB. Yes, I had tried that one as well but the issue is that it is directly going to the increment statement before the API response. I had tried async await on both the function but that doesn't work for me.